# Automatize behavior in Android: open external app, take a screenshot and return to other app

Tags: android

I have an app that must call an activity of another app, take a screenshot and then return to previous activity. All those operations must be done without user interaction.

I am able only to call the external app activity, but then i can do nothing because i have no possibility to write code in external app to take screenshot and return to my app.

Someone know if there is a way to automatize this process.

Comment: Have you checked at UIAutomator options if you don't want an external app for this?